# installation mysqldump

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-9.04, mysqldump

i use linux ubuntu..i try to copy db and type some mysqldump command..
but at terminal show:

```
The program 'mysqldump' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-5.0
 * mysql-client-5.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
bash: mysqldump: command not found
```

how to get mysqldump for my pc?
i've tried to follow the instruction,but show like below:

```
Err http://ubuntu-ashisuto.ubuntulinux.jp jaunty/main libnet-daemon-perl 0.43-1
  Could not connect to ubuntu-ashisuto.ubuntulinux.jp:80 (122.216.218.146), connection timed out
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about ... doing what was printed on the terminal?

```
% sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.1
```

or

```
% sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.0
```

(pick the right version based on whats installed on your machine)

Comment: i've been try to do that but show connection time out.

Answer (score 11):

For CentOS, RedHat and Fedora install:

```
sudo yum install mysql
```

Comment: Do you know if this installs the server as well as the client binaries?

Comment: Apparently the package in yum for the server is `sudo yum install mysql-server`. `sudo yum install mysql` is fine for client.

Answer (score 0):

Install the mysql client package.

In a terminal try the command `sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.1`

(I would have thought that the message you got was clear enough, really.)

Comment: i've tried it but show error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change the mirror ( repository) . Follow the steps mentioned in [this](http://tipotheday.com/2008/05/07/slow-downloads-with-apt-get-change-repos-with-select-best-server/) tutorial. After changing it , you can use the commands mentioned by @Akira

Comment: show "No suitable download server was found".

Comment: check your source file which is located at /etc/apt/sources.list and follow this tutorial, if you dont find any mirror under that file.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories?action=show&redirect=AddingRepositoriesHowto